# USB / WIN7 pro 64 bit /. Code 43 error on music recorder

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit

My Tascam model DP-32 is a music recorder with a USB interface. The USB works fine on my Vista 32 bit laptop, and my other desktop (XP-32 bit). However, a  new PC with WIN 7 64 bit refuses to acknowledge the unit's USB. Returns Code 43.

I tried different cords, tried every USB port on the new machine.  All other USB devices are working properly IE mice, cameras, interfaces, etc.

One other thing I am looking into is that the device may be set for FAT32 or HFS+, so I even loaded up a MAC reader, to no avail.  Reformatting to NTSF is not an option because this is a machine, not a drive, however normally shows up USB as an external thumb drive for file transfers.

*whew* long winded...

Any thoughts?

Thanks - Mike

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of that error code?

Answer (score 0):

I spent an hour and fifteen minutes with   Dell support on my pesky machine. The rep logged onto my PC, re-installed drivers, flashed BIOS, did it all.

Same results afterwards. Works in some ports, not others.

A new motherboard is on the way.